# Angular js update directive after updating input value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a directive to create a restriction to display only multiples of a number.
The number is calculated based on 2 input values, number of **teams** and number of **groups**; (teams/groups)-1.

I used css to show red when the user types an invalid value in **rounds**, based on the restriction mentioned.

It's working properly initially, but when the values of the **teams** and **groups** get updated in the form, the directive doesn't update.

I've tried using $watch as I saw in some answers, but it didn't work, or maybe I didn't know how to implement it properly in my case.

Note: I've defined [[]] instead of {{}} to avoid conflict with the template engine volt, it's define and works properly, so that isn't the problem.

Any help would be appreciated, my code below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="angApp">
  <div ng-controller="DrawController">
    <form action="" name="drawForm" role="form" method="post" >

      <input id="teams" name="teams" ng-model="competition.teams" required="" ng-change="getTeams()" type="number">

      <select id="groups" name="groups" ng-options="n for n in groups track by n" ng-model="competition.groups" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value="" class="">Seleccione el número de grupos</option>
      </select>

      <input id="rounds" name="rounds" ng-model="competition.rounds" data-multiple-validator="[[competition.teams]]" data-groups="[[competition.groups]]" type="number">

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('angApp', []);

app.config(
  function($interpolateProvider)
  {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  }
)

app.controller(
  'DrawController',
  function($scope)
  {
    var competition = {
      teams : 8,
      groups : 1,
      finalists : {'value': 0, 'label': '0'},
      rounds : 7,
      type : 'league',
      test : 3
    }
    $scope.competition = competition;
    $scope.getTeams = function() {
      $scope.groups = [];
      var maxGroups = Math.floor(($scope.competition.teams)/2);

      $scope.competition.teams % 2 === 0 ? (i = 2, j = 1) : (i = 3, j = 2);

      $scope.groups[0] = 1;
      k = 1;
      for (i; i <= maxGroups; i += j) {
        if($scope.competition.teams % i === 0){
          $scope.groups[k] = i;
          k++;
        }
      }

    };
    $scope.getTeams();
  }
);

app.directive('multipleValidator', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }

      var multiple = parseInt(attr.multipleValidator)/parseInt(attr.groups)-1;

      if (!multiple) {
        return;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$validators.multipleValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !!modelValue && modelValue%multiple === 0;
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the directive's scope option to map the controller's scope and the directive's scope

You can refer this tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pLry26yUW0